# For how long does a given ASN stay valid?

Tags: ip, maxmind

I am using the latest `ASN` database from `maxmind`

https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/ .

How far back in time are these mappings valid? Do they change often (every 6 months, every 2 years)?

I am asking this because I want to know if a given `ASN` can be used with historical `ip` addresses. Can someone share some insights here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is fixed duration for the ASN update. It changes every day because of allocation and reallocation of AS.

You should always use the latest ASN with the current IP address.

Comment: thanks Michael but sorry I do not understand what you mean. Of course I should always use the latest ASN but is the mapping really changing every day? Is it completely wrong to use the current ASN dataset for some IPs collected in the last few months?